# vb.net odp.net/ how to use ExecuteNonQuery() in insert?

Tags: vb.net, odp.net

I'm having an error given for the following code:

```
    Public Function Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim oradb As String = "Data Source=fbdata;User Id=fbtrain;Password=password;"
    Using conn As New OracleConnection(oradb)

        Using cmd As New OracleCommand

            conn.CreateCommand()

            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO BID " _
            + "(BID_ID, BID_NAME, BID_NAMEID, BID_STATUS, BID_FROM, BID_TO, BID_OWNER, NEW_USER, NEW_ZEIT, CHG_USER, CHG_ZEIT, AKTIV) VALUES " _
            + "(:1, :2, :2, '00', TO_DATE('01-JUL-16', 'DD-MON-RR'), TO_DATE('30-JUN-2099', 'DD-MON-RR'), '1', '1', SYSDATE, '1', SYSDATE, ' ')"

            Dim pcountbid As New OracleParameter
            pcountbid.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Decimal

            Dim pprname As New OracleParameter
            pprname.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2

            pprname.Value = prname
            pcountbid.Value = countbid

            cmd.Parameters.Add(pcountbid)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pprname)

            conn.Open()
            Return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using

End Function
```

the error is :

InvalidOperationException was unhandled

All i want to do is bind these values and excecute this query to insert the data into my database.

Answer (score 1):

When using bind by position mode, which is the default and as you have done here, you must add the parameters to the `OracleParameterCollection` collection in the same order as they appear in the SQL statement. That means you actually will have THREE parameters, even though 2 of your's are the same (though I question if that's really true further down). So your code would become like this

```
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO BID " _
    + "(BID_ID, BID_NAME, BID_NAMEID, BID_STATUS, BID_FROM, BID_TO, BID_OWNER, NEW_USER, NEW_ZEIT, CHG_USER, CHG_ZEIT, AKTIV) VALUES " _
    + "(:1, :2, :3, '00', TO_DATE('01-JUL-16', 'DD-MON-RR'), TO_DATE('30-JUN-2099', 'DD-MON-RR'), '1', '1', SYSDATE, '1', SYSDATE, ' ')"

    Dim pcountbid As New OracleParameter
    pcountbid.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Decimal '<- ID decimal or really Int32???

    Dim pprname As New OracleParameter
    pprname.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2

    Dim pprnameID As New OracleParameter
    pprname.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32 'change to whatever type you really need

    pprname.Value = prname
    pprnameID.Value = CInt(prname) 'change as needed
    pcountbid.Value = countbid

    cmd.Parameters.Add(pcountbid)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(pprname)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(pprnameID)
```

However, I think you also have some variable type issues as noted in my comments above. Decimal doesn't make sense as an ID field to me. You were also putting the same value in for BID_NAME and BID_NAMEID - shouldn't one be varchar2 and the other a number (in Oracle, typ Int32 in .Net) and are they really supposed to be the same value? Anyway, once you compare your table column types to what you have in your variables, you can convert as needed. Finally, to help keep your order straight, I'd rewrite the parameter code to group it like this

```
    Dim pcountbid As New OracleParameter
    pcountbid.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Decimal '<- ID decimal or really Int32???
    pcountbid.Value = countbid
    cmd.Parameters.Add(pcountbid)

    Dim pprname As New OracleParameter
    pprname.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2
    pprname.Value = prname
    cmd.Parameters.Add(pprname)

    Dim pprnameID As New OracleParameter
    pprname.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32 'change to whatever type you really need
    pprnameID.Value = CInt(prname) 'change as needed
    cmd.Parameters.Add(pprnameID)
```

Comment: I want both BID_NAME and BID_NAMEID to have the same string value from prname. 

However, even after changing the decimal to int32 and using 3 sets of values for binding, the same error persists.

Any other ideas?

Comment: @SamaanShameem Can you show the create statement you used for the BID table?